# Make something happen every 500 points

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am working on a game and I want to make something happen every 500 points, and make it infinity expandable.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `if score%500 == 0 then ....`

Comment: @Bart - What is player earns 20 points and score jumps from 490 to 510 ?

Comment: maybe increment points by one each time, have a function you call passing a parameter which is how many times to loop, the loop contains `points++` and `if points % 500 == 0`??

Comment: @egor Then they get nothing. NOTHING!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if math.floor(points/500) ~= math.floor(last_points/500) then
  -- do something
end
last_points = points
```

Comment: There's a little more complexity here, since we don't know if points can decrease (like being spent on something). So I would make a change to use > rather that ~=, as well as possibly tracking "earned_points" in addition to points/last_points.

Comment: @TomJacques - Of course, this should be counter of earned points.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I interpret the question correctly, this should be pretty safe:

```
if math.floor(points/500) >= math.floor(maximum_points/500) then
  maximum_points = points
  -- do something
end
```